# How can I create a line pivot chart with two lines?

Tags: excel

Ideally I need to have one line representing 2019 revenue, and another line representing 2020 revenue instead of one line and the years on the axis below. Months will be the x-axis label.

How can I achieve this with a pivot chart?

[image]

Comment: Need slicers though... creating a dynamic dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Within your data, if you have just one column for Date, then create more date columns (one for year and one for month). Then, just put your Month in categories and Year in Series.

[image]